Unable to Execute Databricks Notebook from Azure Data Factory
When I attempt to execute a Databricks notebook from Azure Datafactory with a Base parameter 'entityName',see image, I get the error:

My Base parameters are as follows:

I also have the following widgets in my Databricks Notebook
dbutils.widgets.text("entityName", "test" ,"Entity Name")
entityName = dbutils.widgets.get("entityName")
Any thoughts why I'm getting the error?

Could you please provide how you are giving values to the pipeline parameter?

Along with that please provide the error message in notebook execution.

Hi @Bhavani, I just figured it out. The following working in my stored procedure activity: @activity('Run Notebook').Output.runOutput.TableName


When no value provided for the parameter then the above error will occur. To resolve the error, provide value for pipeline parameter as shown below:

Then the notebook activity will run successfully without any error as shown below:


Hi @Bhavani, I'm confused with your answer, because I did provide a name. Are you saying that adding a parameter as I showed in my screen shot means it's empty?

Did you add any value to the pipeline parameter? If you didn't provide no value then you will get above error

I added the following to pipeline vaue ```@pipeline().parameters.TableName``

You are just accessing the defined pipeline parameter using ```@pipeline().parameters.TableName``, you should assign a value to the parameter, check this document once.
